# Origin of the word Permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, terminology, history

Who coined the word ["permittivity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity)? It appears that first usage was in 1887. Please cite your source.

Comment: Excuse me. How do you know it started in 1887? Your Ref?

Answer (score 3):

Oliver Heaviside ["On the Self Inductance of Wires"](https://archive.org/details/s5philosophicalm24lond) Philosophical Magazine Series 5, volume 24, issue 146, 1887, page 79.

Answer (score 0):

No it was known well before 1887.  Faraday was looking for a word to indicate a material through which an electrical field would penetrate.  He asked William Whewell - a polymath at Cambridge (UK), who suggested dielectric (considering dia-electric a bit clumsy): "As to the name for the antithetical classes of bodies, I consider thus. I suppose you called one class dimagnetic from analogy with dielectric. I think you ought to have said diamagnetic; for the bodies through (dia) which electricity goes would have been called diaelectric, but that vowels in such cases coalesce. I think you may keep diamagnetic for this class, and give to the opposite class a name implying that they rank along with magnetic bodies. I propose paramagnetic. (Whewell's emphasis)"

See:

J. Daintith (1994). Biographical Encyclopedia of Scientists. CRC Press. p. 943. ISBN 0-7503-0287-9.

Jump up ^ James, Frank A.J.L., editor. The Correspondence of Michael Faraday, Volume 3, 1841–1848, "Letter 1798, William Whewell to Faraday, p. 442.". The Institution of Electrical Engineers, London, United Kingdom, 1996. ISBN 0-86341-250-5

Comment: is this relevant. OP is asking about "permittivity" as a word, not "paramagnetic".